# Call static method on null object

Tags: java, null

I'm curious to know how would you explain this task I found in this [quiz](http://java-quizapp.rhcloud.com/)?
Even when the `getFoo` method returns `null`, the output is still `Getting Object JavaQuiz` . I think it should be `NullPointerException`.

```
   public class Foo {

        static String name = " JavaQuiz";

        static Foo getFoo() {
            System.out.print("Getting Object");
            return null;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(getFoo().name);
        }

   }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Accessing a static method or variable can be done via a null reference for the class that contains that static method/variable.

Since `name` is static, `getFoo().name` has the same result as `Foo.name` or just `name`, regardless of whether or not `getFoo()` returns `null`.

However, it is always better to use the class name when accessing a static method/variable, since it makes it clear that you intended to access a static member.

Comment: Sir, I know this is probably not the kind of comment to write on SO. But, your knowledge is truly astounding. Always learning from your answers. :)

Answer (score 2):

`static` members of a `class` are `class` level Members its means there is no need of Object to access these `static` Members.`

It automatically loaded when `classloader` of `jvm` loads the class. So here in this case

```
static String name = " JavaQuiz"; //load when class get loaded by JVM class loader.
```

This `static` variable will exists in memory just after class `Foo` is getting loaded into the `jvm`.

```
static Foo getFoo() {  //method is also a static Member automatically loaded at Class Loading.
            System.out.print("Getting Object");
            return null;
        }
```

And same will be applied with this static method `getFoo()`.

So Here   `System.out.println(getFoo().name);`. 
Here is a example to abbriviate my Answer

```
class StaticExample
{
    static String abc ="India";
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        StaticExample obj = null;
        System.out.println("Value is ==>" + obj.abc + StaticExample.abc + abc);
    }
}
```

Output:-

```
 Value is ==>IndiaIndiaIndia
```

here this line of code will also produce the output.

```
     System.out.println(((Ideone)null).abc); // this will also print India.
```

Output:-

```
 Value is ==>India
```

> Note:- I think there  is confusion about `getFoo()` method but if `.name` makes a ambiguity. `name` is a  static member so it can access using either `className` or any `null` reference . So, Here you may assume this scenario such that this `name` variable is accessed with any null reference .

Hope you Got the point.

Answer (score 0):

Disassembling `(javap -c Foo)` the byte code of Foo.java file reveals the under the hood information as to why you don't see a NullPointerException when the `name` is `static`.

With the above code, when disassembled it produces the following output.

[image: With Static field]

If we look at the yellow box, we see that the compiler identifies that we are trying to access a static field and so it places the **getstatic** instruction to get the field `name`. So this effectively doesn't use the instance returned from `getFoo` method to get the value of `name` field and so no NPE is raised.

---

If we remove the `static` keyword before the `String name = " JavaQuiz";`, it results in below disassembled code.

[image: Without static keyword]

Here we can see that java compiler instructs to use `getfield` instruction and this would invoked on the instance i.e., returned from `getFoo` method. So, this would raise a NPE if the `getFoo` method returns `null`.

So effectively, in this case, the java compiler does the magic during the compilation, i.e., if it the code is calling static field it places `getstatic` instruction that doesn't result in using the object reference.

We can find more information on instruction set [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html).